# detecting a valid CSS document with PHP?

Tags: php, file-type

Is there a way to have PHP detect if a file is a valid CSS document?

Comment: Is it something like extension is .CSS and file content does not have CSS format?

Comment: you could allso use http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: maybe put that as an answer, if it works you'll earn yourself a tick ;)

Comment: Can't seem to find a way to pass a file into CSSTidy, any help would be awesome!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could use CURL to submit the .css file to the W3 CSS validator.  Scraping the results to determine whether the validator thinks the css in question is valid would be a bit of a challenge though, especially if you want to extract the list of errors if it's not valid.

If you hammer their validator with a lot of requests, however, they could possibly block you.  Be aware of that if you do go the curl route.

Comment: good idea, but it makes the website so slow, I think CSSTidy should be a better solution

Comment: Well you only have to validate the CSS file when it's changed, not every time that you load it.  This shouldn't happen all that frequently.